# Keeping data in a constructor for use across multiple objects

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have a simple function which I use as a "parent" function in order to store data to be shared across multiple child objects. Here is my parent "Calc()":

```
function Calc() {
  this.hasBeenCalculated = {
    child1: false,
    child2: false,
  }
  this.updateGlobalCalculationState = ({calcType, hasBeenCalculated}) => {
    this.hasBeenCalculated[calcType] = hasBeenCalculated;
  }
}
```

Here is a "child" object that I want to update the Calc() above:

```
const ChildCalc1 = {
  setup() {
    // link up this object to the main Calc prototype
    Calc.call(this);
  },
  calculate() {
    this.updateGlobalCalculationState({calcType: 'child1', hasBeenCalculated: true})

  }
}
const ChildCalc2 = {
  setup() {
    // link up this object to the main Calc prototype
    Calc.call(this);
  },
  calculate() {
    this.updateGlobalCalculationState({calcType: 'child2', hasBeenCalculated: true})

  }
}
```

The children and parent are connected by the prototypes for each:

```
ChildCalc1.prototype = Object.create(Calc.prototype);
ChildCalc1.setup();
ChildCalc2.prototype = Object.create(Calc.prototype);
ChildCalc2.setup();
```

Each time a child has been calculated, I want it to update the parent Calc() "hasBeenCalculated" object, but when ever I call to update that object, it resets to the default. The object updates aren't persisting over the multple children.

Where am I going wrong here?

EDIT:

I've added an update for how each child is created.

Comment: Try `this.__proto__.hasBeenCalculated[calcType]` with assignation ...

Comment: I think you are looking for composition, not inheritance.

Comment: @FrV No, that won't work. Also `.__proto__` is deprecated and should no longer be used.

Comment: Why not utilize classes in ES6 since you're using lambdas?

Comment: @Bergi you can use "class" variable or a an unlinked object

Comment: Your `Calc` is a constructor function while your `ChildCalc1` is an object literal. Is that on purpose? "*The object updates aren't persisting over the multple children.*" - can you please show that code that creates multiple children (and presumably some parent instances as well)?

Comment: @super this is some legacy code of which I don't want to change much of, so I'm trying now to change too much.

Comment: Why would you use a lambda if it was legacy code?

Comment: @Bergi I've updated how the other children are created. The ChildCalc1 is an object literal on purpose yes - will this affect the Calc constructor though?

Comment: @super I'm trying to get something added and working at the moment and use lambda's without thinking about it :/

Comment: @JamesG By doing `Calc.call(this)` on the two `ChildCalcN` objects, you initialise two distinct parents. This `setup` thing is not going to work out.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for your help, I get what's wrong with it now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The children and parent are connected by the prototypes

They should not. You are looking to create a tree structure here. No inheritance is necessary for that. Your `.prototype` code doesn't even work as your children are not constructor functions.

You should just do

```
const parent = new Calc();
const childCalc1 = {
  parent,
  calculate() {
    this.parent.updateGlobalCalculationState({calcType: 'child1', hasBeenCalculated: true});
  }
};
const childCalc2 = {
  parent: parent,
  calculate() {
    this.parent.updateGlobalCalculationState({calcType: 'child2', hasBeenCalculated: true});
  }
};
```

There is only one `Calc` instance, the `parent`, and both your children refer to it.

You could potentially make it work by letting the child objects inherit from the `parent` object, but there's no point in that. Use [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

You might want to create a `ChildCalc` constructor/class however that takes the parent instance as an argument, and reduces code duplication between the children. You then would be able to just do

```
const parent = new Calc();
const childCalc1 = new ChildCalc(parent, 'child1');
const childCalc2 = new ChildCalc(parent, 'child2');
```